# Controlar conexión a internet Azure en Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xamarin, azure, xamarin.forms

Buenas a todos, resulta que tengo una aplicación en Xamarin que funciona correctamente siempre y cuando tenga conexión a internet. Me gustaría controlar esto de tal manera que si hubiese algún corte o algún tipo de problema la aplicación no diese ningún error (En la actualidad si hubiese algún corte la aplicación daría un cierre inesperado debido a que no está controlado). He intentado un par de cosas pero no funcionan...La aplicación se está desarrollando como plataforma cruzada (windows, ios y android). A continuación expongo el código que tengo. A ver si me podéis ayudar.

Primero tengo la clase "AzuredataService" que es la que realiza las conexiones y demás

> ```
> public class AzureDataService
> {
>     public MobileServiceClient MobileService { get; set; } //Conexion al backend
>      IMobileServiceSyncTable<Ficha> tablaFicha; //Objeto de la clase Ficha.    public async Task Initialize()
>     {
>         if (isInitialized) 
>             return;
>         //Instanciamos el objeto MobileServide declarado arriba, pasandole al constructor la url del servicio
>         MobileService = new MobileServiceClient("http://linkbdd");
>
>         //Guardamos datos en una base de datos local, después se suben a Azure cuando haya conexion
>         const string path = "bbddMuestra.db";
>
>         var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(path);//Creamos la BD
>
>         //Definimos la tabla
>         store.DefineTable<Ficha>();
>
>         //Inicializacion asincrona
>         await MobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, new MobileServiceSyncHandler());
>
>         //Inicializamos las tabla
>         tablaFicha = MobileService.GetSyncTable<Ficha>();
>
>         isInitialized = true;
>
>     }
>
>     public async Task<IEnumerable<Ficha>> ObtenerDatos()
>     {
>         await Initialize();
>         await SyncFicha();
>         //Selecciona los datos que me interesan...
>         return await tablaFicha.OrderBy(a => a.Id).ToEnumerableAsync();
>     }   
>     public async Task SyncFicha()
>     {
>         await tablaVehiculos.PullAsync("Ficha", tablaFicha.CreateQuery());
>         await MobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();
>     }
> ```

Hasta aqui todo correcto. Ahora muestro la clase en la que implemento la anterior

> ```
> public partial class ListaFichas : ContentPage    
> {
>     public static ObservableCollection<Ficha> ficha;      
>
>      public ListaFichas ()        
>      {        
>         InitializeComponent ();
>         ficha = new ObservableCollection<Ficha>();        
>      }
>      protected async override void OnAppearing()
>      {
>         base.OnAppearing();
>
>         ficha.Clear();    //Justo en esta línea es donde recoge el metodo con la  conexión para obtener datos en la app
>         var ligas = await App.AzureService.ObtenerDatos();
>
>         foreach(var item in ligas)
>         {
>             Ficha fi = item;
>             ficha.Add(fi);
>         }
>         lsvFichas.ItemsSource = ficha;
>
>     }
> }
> ```

¿De qué manera podría hacerlo? Me gustaría utilizar un Display para indicar que no hay conexión, o en su defecto un DisplayActionSheet que es similar pero puedes utilizar eventos en los botones si no me equivoco (nunca lo he utilizado).

Espero vuestra ayuda. Muchas gracias y un cordial saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Por que no pruebas el siguiente nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Connectivity/

Los ejemplos de uso estan en su sitio de GitHub: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin,

Saludos